# Why is CSS not applying to HTML?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know why my CSS won't apply to my HTML. I don't think I have done anything wrong, but it just won't apply. It's probably some really stupid beginner error, but I have no idea what I'm doing incorrectly.

**My HTML:**

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="imagetest.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Antic+Didone' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
<div id="imagesWrapper">
<!-------------------------------DEVIDER------------------------------->
<div id="img1Wrap" class="imgWrapGlobal">
    <img id="img1" class="images" src="img/img1.png">
</div>


<div id="img2Wrap" class="imgWrapGlobal">
    <img id="img2" class="images" src="img/img2.png">
</div>


<div id="img3Wrap" class="imgWrapGlobal">
    <img id="img3" class="images" src="img/img3.png">
</div>


<div id="img4Wrap" class="imgWrapGlobal">
    <img id="img4" class="images" src="img/img4.png">
</div>


<div id="img5Wrap" class="imgWrapGlobal">
    <img id="img5" class="images" src="img/img5.png">
</div>


<div id="img6Wrap" class="imgWrapGlobal">
    <img id="img6" class="images" src="img/img6.png">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**My CSS:**

```
.images{
width:200px;

}
```

Comment: does your css file load ? is it at the same location as the html file?

Comment: That looks like it should work. Are you sure your 'imagetest.css' is loading?

Comment: Are you sure your css is in the directory that you are calling?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is `href` and not `src` what you have to use in `link`-tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="imagetest.css">
```

Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_link.asp).

Comment: Hahaha, of course :p Silly me! I'll accept your answer as soon as possible.